# jQuery up key / down key keypress detection not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 40) {
            alert("down pressed");
        } else if (code == 38) {
            alert("up pressed");
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to detect if the down key or up key is pressed.  Why isn't it working?

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/K9uDn/10/

I'm in chrome

Comment: The event isn't firing.

Comment: Well, it works if I change `keypress` to `keydown` or `keyup` (and if I remove those `self.gotIt()` and `self.forgotIt()`). I strongly recommend that you use `keyup` or `keydown` anyways, even if you didn't have this issue... it's much better, and everything is predictable with it. `keydown` should replace `keypress` as well.

Comment: [jQuery normalizes `keyCode` and `charCode` with `which`, so you don't need to check them both. Just use `which`.](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: You're jsFiffle works but to make it work you need focus on the element. Thus clicking the box in the right bottom will make your script work on jsFiddle. jQuery quote: "A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus."

Comment: @Michael What browser are you using? That doesn't work for me in Chrome. I think `keypress` is more of an IE thing.

Comment: Hmm i'm using firefox no problem here as long as i focus the html element in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use **keydown** instead of **keypress**, some browsers does not fire **keypress** when an "special key (like arrows)" are pressed

Comment: Yup according to jQuery website: 
_Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms._

Comment: Be careful using keypress to detect special keys.  On some platforms it will only fire once, on others will fire repetitively.  Try this: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/20/jquery-keyup-function-demo/ on your webbrowser and platform, and see how often Ctrl fires when held down.  On OEL 6.x it fires once.  On Windows 7 it fires repetitively.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `keypress` method isn't very stable. Use `on('keydown')` instead.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/K9uDn/9/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **Fiddle** of a fixed version of the javascript code
[with extra buttons trapped using a switch/case statement](http://jsfiddle.net/K9uDn/168/)

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        switch (code){
          case 34:
            alert("Page down pressed");
            break;
          case 33:
            alert("Page up pressed");
            break;
          case 40:
            alert("Down pressed");
            break;
          case 38:
            alert("Up pressed");
            break;
          case 37:
            alert("Left pressed");
            break;
          case 39:
            alert("Right pressed");
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

on('keyup') does not work in IE.  Not in version 9 at least.