# Page scrolls rather than lightbox content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

Im currently using lightbox style overlays for my 'Read More' content on this site:

But unfortunately my content in the lightbox doesn't scroll, instead the page in the background scrolls instead.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to confirm, but I imagine you need to disable scrollify while you're lightbox is being displayed.

There's documentation on [the scrollify website](http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods-continued).

In particular you will want:

```
$.scrollify.disable();
```

and

```
$.scrollify.enable();
```

---

## Update

In the version you are using (I don't know if there's any other versions, I've never used the library before) there is a bug on the disable() method:

```
$.scrollify.disable = function() {
    disable = true;
};
```

`disable` is not defined. This variable name needs update to `disabled`. (Check for an update to the script before you change this manually.)

To get what you want working you need to do the following. Let's take your "READ JOB DESCRIPTION" button as an example. You have the following code for showing and hiding the lightbox:

```
            // SERVICES 2 - OVERLAY - SHOW
            $( "#srvcs2" ).click(function() {
                $( "#services2-overlay" ).removeClass('animated fadeOutDown').css('left', '0').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                $( "#services2-overlay .container" ).css('opacity', '0').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            });

            // SERVICES 2 - OVERLAY - HIDE
            $( "#services2-overlay-close" ).click(function() {
                $( "#services2-overlay" ).removeClass('animated fadeInUp').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
                $( "#services2-overlay .container" ).removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
            });
```

You will need to add the scrollify enable and disable code in here (and to all other handlers), like this:

```
            // SERVICES 2 - OVERLAY - SHOW
            $( "#srvcs2" ).click(function() {
                $.scrollify.disable();
                $( "#services2-overlay" ).removeClass('animated fadeOutDown').css('left', '0').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                $( "#services2-overlay .container" ).css('opacity', '0').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            });

            // SERVICES 2 - OVERLAY - HIDE
            $( "#services2-overlay-close" ).click(function() {
                $.scrollify.enable();
                $( "#services2-overlay" ).removeClass('animated fadeInUp').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
                $( "#services2-overlay .container" ).removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
            });
```

Note the addition of `$.scrollify.disable();` and `$.scrollify.enable();`

This will disable scrollify when the lightbox is opened and enable it again when you close the lightbox.

Comment: Yes i too believe this is what is needed but I'm afraid I've no idea how to go about implementing this - any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @MKDesigns I've add an update to the answer, hopefully it will get you sorted!

Comment: Hi Darren, adding the above seems to break the 'Read More' button & now the lightbox no longer gets called - any thoughts?

Comment: @MKDesigns It looks like your whole website is broken now! Check out line 85 of your script.js file. You've got a ( character out of place - $(.scrollify.disable(); As mentioned in the Update above, you need to update the jquery.scrollify.js file - line 511; change the variable name "disable" to "disabled". That should sort if.

Comment: Ok site is back online again - thank you so much for spotting those mistakes. However the 'Read More' button isn't calling the lightbox - any ideas?

Comment: Ok I've got the 'Read More' button calling the lightbox agin but the page in the background is still scrolling instead of being disabled - why would this be if Scrollify is now disabled during launch of the lightbox?

Comment: That's annoying, it looks like this scrollify library is a bit incomplete. As a workaround you could call the destroy method instead (this definitely works) - $.scrollify.destroy(); The only problem is, this gets rid of scrollify, so you'll need to set it up again each time you close the lightbox.

Comment: Ok I've updated the Scrollify js (it was a version behind) & now all seems to work better but i still can't get the page in the background of the overlay to stop scrolling - any thoughts?

Comment: @MKDesigns Glad you got it sorted! You want to set the style of the body to overflow:hidden; So set this on click of a button that launches the lightbox, and set it back to overflow:visible when you close the lightbox. $("body").css({"overflow":"hidden"});

Comment: Works perfectly now! Page in background locks in place while the content of the overlay scrolls - just one slight problem...The arrow keys still scroll the background page, can this be locked too?

Comment: I don't get that problem with the arrow keys actually. I'm using Chrome. You could intercept these key presses and preventDefault() on them.

Comment: Im using Safari & your right it doesn't happen on chrome - any idea how to target this on Safari?

Comment: There would be no harm in targeting all browsers. See this answer on how to capture up / down arrow key presses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412033/jquery-up-key-down-key-keypress-detection-not-working

Comment: Im so sorry but I'm not sure how to use this info - would you be kind enough to explain or show me the code needed to disable the key functions please?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to reply to this. Yes, I agree with @Basic , I think you should ask a new question so as not to muddy this one up any more.